# Handle message view

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, swift4

So I am implementing the network check in my app,
which check for the network connection in `viewDidAppear` and shows the `offline label` in absence of internet and show `back online label` when the user comes online.

The problem with this is 'back online label' is shown every time user navigates to a new VC which creates a bad user experience.

I want to show back online label only when user goes offline first and then comes online.

One way is to keep count but I think there might be a better solution to this problem

Any suggestions?

Comment: initially hide both label in ViewDidloadMethod and make label visible based on network condition in viewWillAppear Method

Comment: Yes, or you can play with alpha also :)

Answer (score 0):

you know the state when when user goes offline first and then comes online, you show the alert `back online label

then you have to save the state that you have shown the alert

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "backOnline")
```

in every time in `viewDidAppear` you may add checking

```
if let backOnline = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "backOnline") as? Bool, backOnline == true {
    //back online shown once, I don't want to show
} else {
    // never shown back online 
}
```